PowerShell: escaping rules for CLI calls with special character sequences
I have gone through much documentation on Powershell 5.1 escaping rules, like what is described in this answer and this other answer but couldn't find a way to make code with special character sequences in the string work when it is send through cmd and powershell.
I've provide a simplify example here.
$specialChar = "`nMatch"
$rmtScript = "powershell Write-Output '$specialChar'"
cmd.exe /c $script1

Gives an error:
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

If I remove the `n in $specialChar it works fine.
Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?
EDIT: My ultimate goal is to send a script through ssh that writes to a file, such as:
$specialChar = "`nMatch all`n"
$rmtScript = "powershell Add-Content -Force -Verbose " +
"-Path c:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config -Value '$specialChar'"
ssh $Username@$ComputerIP $rmtScript

The script should modify the file in Path with the format given through the special character sequences, so create a new line, write the words and new line. This code and the simplified example I added send the same error message when executed.

Note that you can fundamentally only pass single-line command lines to cmd /c

@mklement0 Where did you find that information? From the command line help I get cmd /? /C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates

@JackOA, the quoted information isn't detailed enough. You can verify yourself that it doesn't work  by trying cmd /c "echo a\nb"andcmd /c "echo a^`nb", both of which print just a(using`r`n` doesn't help either).

@mklement0 Thanks for your comment, but I'm not sure what you mean by the quoted information isn't detailed enough. Also, your examples do not reflect my problem, as the command called after cmd /c is powershell which will format the string. You could try cmd /c "powershell Write-output 'ab'" vs cmd /c "powershell Write-output 'anb'"` to recreate the problem asked.

@JackOA: I meant that the quote from the documentation isn't detailed enough: it doesn't mention the de facto single-line constraint. My examples still apply, because it is always cmd.exe that mishandles a multiline string, irrespective of what command you're passing to /c. I'm hoping my answer will clarify.

You fundamentally can not pass a multiline command to cmd /c[1] and, assuming that the ssh command you're ultimately interested in targets a Windows machine that uses the default shell,[2] which is also cmd.exe, you'll have the same problem there.
Workaround:
Avoid literal newlines in your PowerShell command by deferring the expansion of escape sequence `n and letting the target PowerShell instance expand it:
# Note the use of '...' here, to prevent up-front expansion of `n
$specialChar = '`nMatch' 
# Note the use of embedded \"...\", to ensure that `n is expanded by PowerShell
$rmtScript = "powershell Write-Output \`"$specialChar\`""
cmd.exe /c $rmtScript

Alternatively, use $([char 10]) or [char] 10 in expressions.
Caveats:

Depending on what PowerShell edition / version you're calling from, you may need to perform additional escaping of the embedded " chars. when calling ssh.exe rather than cmd.exe /C directly.

See this answer to your follow-up question.


The above works robustly with special characters other than newlines  in the value of $specialChar, but makes the value subject to whitespace normalization; e.g.,
foo    bar would become foo bar.

To avoid that in a cmd.exe /C call (which indirectly applies also to ssh.exe calls when targeting Windows machines with the default shell configuration) while preserving the robustness of the call, enclose the overall (implied) -Command argument in "...", and enclose $specialChar in "^""..."^"" (sic), with additional up-front escaping of the " chars. as `" in this case.

As an aside: pwsh.exe, the PowerShell (Core) 7 CLI more simply accepts "".



Therefore:
$rmtScript = "powershell -NoProfile `"Write-Output `"^`"`"$specialChar`"^`"`"`""

See this answer for additional information.

[1] You can verify this as follows from PowerShell: cmd /c "echo a`nb" and cmd /c "echo a^`nb" both print just a (and using `r`n doesn't help either), i.e. the 2nd line is ignored. Therefore, something like cmd /c "powershell -c 'a`nb'" executes a syntactically broken command, powershell -c 'a, resulting in the error you saw. 
[2] However, a target server's default shell is configurable from there, and it is possible to make PowerShell the default shell, in which case you can specify PowerShell code directly in an ssh call, and you're also not subject to the single-line constraint; see the docs.

@JackOA Without seeing the specific command line, I'm not sure what the problem is. So, yes, please open a new question, not least because it would be good to know if additional rules must be observed when passing a command line to ssh.
